# How to add a JPanel button for boolean values?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I am new to swing,
I have a method which returns values in true or false (boolean) format. 
I need to display a flag using `JPanel` which displays true or false values.

How can I do this?

Comment: *"How can I do this?"*  By adding some code.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: BTW - a `JCheckBox` is a good component for displaying true/false values.  Alternately, depending upon the requirement, a `JToggleButton`, `JRadioButton` or enabled/disabled `JButton`..

Comment: You can also do this by changing color of any `Component` say green/red against true/false

Comment: @Sarz Yes, that would be great. Is there a sample for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, `JFrame` is set with `BorderLayout` and you can call it ribbon on bottom, as user interface shown green/red.

```
public class SampleClass extends JFrame{
    JPanel centerPanel;
    JPanel topPanel;
    JButton btn;
    boolean check=true;

    SampleClass(){
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        btn=new JButton("Check");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(200,200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    void add(){
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                if(check){
                    topPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    repaint();
                    check=false;
                }else{
                    topPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    repaint();
                    check=true;
                }
            }
        });
        centerPanel.add(btn);
        add(topPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    void setShow(){
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        SampleClass sc=new SampleClass();
        sc.add();
        sc.setShow();
    }
}
```